# How to separate using characters instead of whitespace in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

I have a text file for example :

> test case 1 Pass
>
> > Test case 2 Pass
> >
> > > etc etc etc

I am able to separate the strings using split() function by whitespace, but I want to separate them using the keyword "Pass"/"Fail", how should I go about it?

my current code supports separation through whitespace but not all text file will have similar value, but they will have "Pass" or "Fail" keywords

```
filestr = ''
f = open('/Users/shashankgoud/Downloads/abc/index.txt',"r")
data=f.read()
for line in data.split('\n'):
    strlist = line.split(' ')
    filestr += (' '.join(strlist[:3]) +','+','.join(strlist[3:]))
    filestr += '\n'

print(filestr)

f1 = open('/Users/shashankgoud/Downloads/abc/index.xlsx',"w")
f1.write(filestr)
f1.close()
```

Comment: Does this look like it might help you?: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module for that, for example:

```py
import re

txt = "test case 1 Pass Test case 2 Pass etc etc etc"
pattern = re.compile(r'(Pass|Fail)')

parts = pattern.split(txt)
joined_parts = [
    parts[i] + parts[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(parts) - 1, 2)
]
joined_parts += [parts[-1]]
print(joined_parts)


>>> ['test case 1 Pass', ' Test case 2 Pass', ' etc etc etc']
```

Comment: while this did help me to seperate using the keyword pass or fail (Thank you for sharing) but I am still unable to separate the text file content, if there's a \n then pass, fail just disappears.. I want them to be there so as to when I convert that text file into excel the pass/fail is listed in separate column.
sorry for being troublesome coder

Comment: @ShashankGoud, now the delimiter won't disappear. See update.